# Deleted ProfileList IDs on Windows 10 and Can't Log In

Tags: windows-10, id

While trying to fix the constant crashes caused by the forced updates on Windows 10 I misunderstood a guide's instructions and deleted every Profile ID as they all had ProfileImagePath and it said to delete the profiles with those. So now when I try to log in it says my password is wrong and tells me the site to change it. If it matters my computer is a HP ENVY Notebook Laptop. Thank You.

Edit: Here is the guide that led me to this mistake: http://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2015/08/08/windows-10-forced-updates-causing-endless-crash-loop/

Comment: Have tried changing the password ? Deleted profilelist ID should give an error saying user account not found I guess

Comment: I changed it using the microsoft password reset, still gives the same message being "That password is incorrect. Make sure you're using the password for your Microsoft account. You can always reset it at account.live.com/reset"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it after going into my Computer's Safe Mode (Clicking restart while holding Shift) and I was able to restore my computer to it's state days before the incident, with documents that had been changed since then still in their newest saves.